# Magento 2 How to send data to Controller with Ajax from a template?

Tags: magento2, controllers, ajax

I'm trying to send some data to my Controller from a template.html using Ajax, so my checkout page does not refresh when I send a custom form, but I don't get anything, the information is an extra field for the sales order, and the fields are empty.
This is my code from the template. This code is just after the `</form>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    "jquery",
    "mage/mage"
],function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#co-shipping-form').mage(
            'validation',
            { 
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://(my server IP)/(folder name)/checkout/Ordercomment/index",
                        data: {comments: 'Test comment from Ajax '},
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            // show some loading icon
                        },
                        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                            // data contains your controller response
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                            console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                            console.log(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
</script>
```

Then this is the part of the controller where I'm trying to receive the data.

```
namespace Vsourz\Ordercomment\Controller\Ordercomment;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Vsourz\Ordercomment\Controller\Index
{
    public function execute()
    {

        $response = $this->resultFactory
            ->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
            ->setData([
                'status'  => "ok",
                'message' => "form submitted correctly"
        ]);

            return $response;

        //This is the field where I want to store the data that comes from Ajax 
 $Ordercomments = $this->getRequest()->getPost('comments');
```

I hope someone can help me! Thank you!

Comment: You are returning data before its save, check your controller code. Check the network tab if data is properly sent or not, check the request and response headers. Add those data as well for better solution

Answer (score 1):

Use `showLoader: true` to show a loader

```
.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: customurl,
        showLoader: true,
        data: {comments: 'Test comment from Ajax'},
        success: function(data)
        {
          console.log(data);
        }
```

You can see post data in the browser console

The following line will be first-line controller file.

```
$value=$this->getRequest()->getPost('comments');
```

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Hello , I tried and did not work, actually it does not send any data and can`t see any message in console.